# Thymeleaf would not resolve html entities

Tags: thymeleaf, html-entities

How do I get thymeleaf to resolve my html entities?

I have the following:

```
<input th:name="title" th:value="Wayne&rsquo;s World" />
```

will simply produce an input element with `"Wayne&rsquo;s World"` instead of `"Wayne's world"`.

Any way to make thymeleaf resolve the html entities?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices.

*First*. Do not use html entities at all. Just escape special symbols using `\`. Note, that you have specify string value in single quotes:

```
<input th:name="title" th:value="'Wayne\'s World'" />
```

*Second*. Use Thymeleaf's [string utility](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings) for escape xml enitites:

```
<input th:name="title" th:value="${#strings.escapeXml('Wayne&rsquo;s World')}" />
```

---

When your string value is coming from controller, don't use `__${}__` preprocess expression. It doesn't needed. Just use Thymeleaf's standard variable expression `${}`. And don't enclose this expression in single quotes. Look at `${title}` variable in next example:

```
<th:block th:include="row::row(attrs='value=${title}, minLength=\'.{1, 16}\', required=true, ... />
```

In this case you can add string value in controller as is, without any escaping:

```
public String method(ModelMap model){
   ... 
   mode.addAttribute("title", "Wayne's world");
   ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the need for the html entity is for cases where there is a quote in the title as shown below. `<th:block th:include="row::row(attrs='value=\'__${title}__\', minLength=\'.{1, 16}\', required=true, title=\'starts with an alphabet 1 and 64\', placeholder=\'Movie title\'')" />`

To escape the quote (i.e. `Wayne'\s World`) causes parsing exception for obvious reasons. To use html entities (i.e. `Wayne&rsquo;s World`) simply prints without evaluation, and to escape it with `#strings.escapeXml` throws same parsing exception as the former for the same reasons.

Comment: @000 it's not clear. Does it mean that you get `${title}` from controller?

Comment: Yes, `${title}` is coming from the controller

Comment: It continues to break. The apostrophe in ${title} creates misplaced quote in the template; causing the parsing error.

Comment: @000 `${tite}` will recognized just in template during processing of `__${attrs}__`. so there is no any unclosed quotes. i checked in Thymeleaf 2.1.4 and Spring 4.1.1. I guess this error related to something else.

Comment: That is quite interesting that thymeleaf could preserve the quotes in the ${title} model attribute. I cannot find error anywhere else. It probably is a thymeleaf bug being that it had not preserved the quote as it supposes to do